# What does the * operator do before an array of attributes?

Tags: ruby

I saw this line of code in an article I was reading and couldn't figure out what the * is.

```
module Presenter
  class Person
    attr_reader :json

    PERSON_ATTRS  = [:person, :attributes]
    COUNTRY_NAME  = PERSON_ATTRS + [:address, :country, :name]
    STREET_NAME   = PERSON_ATTRS + [:address, :street]

    def initialize(person_json)
      @json = person_json
    end

    def country
      json.dig(*COUNTRY_NAME)
    end

    def street
      json.dig(*STREET_NAME)
    end
  end
end
```

It comes before the array of attributes and when I run the code without the * the dig returns nil.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The `*` operator in front of an array is called the splat operator.

The dig method signature takes multiple arguments. If you want to convert an array into a list of arguments, that is what the splat operator does: https://medium.freecodecamp.org/rubys-splat-and-double-splat-operators-ceb753329a78.

The reason why it returns nil is because dig will lookup the key `[:person, :attributes]`:

```rb
json = {person: {attributes: "something"} }
json.dig(*PERSON_ATTRS) # something
```

```
json = {[:person :attributes] => "something"} }
json.dig(PERSON_ATTRS) # something
```

Comment: Thanks for the info!